# Page not rendering properly with DTD

Tags: html, css, doctype

I am making a simple landing page for the web server on my computer. At the moment it looks fine:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Felix's computer</title>
    <style>body{background-color:red;font-family:Zapfino,cursive;text-align:center}img{height:50%}a{text-decoration:none;color:inherit}a:hover{color:blue}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>STOP - Felix's computer</h1>
      <h2>Here be dragons...</h2>
      <img src="dragon.png"><br>
      You may be looking for <a href="~frief17">Felix's page</a>?
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot of page rendering properly]

However, as soon as I include `<!DOCTYPE html>`, it suddenly looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of page rendered with DOCTYPE]

I know that it is because of the difference between 'standards' mode and 'quirks' mode, but what am I doing wrong? What part of the CSS is being interpreted differently?

Answer (score 0):

I think the height is being calculated as a percentage of its container, which is unhelpful in this case.

The "right" way to do this would be to make this a background image on a div, and you resize the image with `background-size`.

For this quick use case, you probably just want to slap the height on your image tag as an HTML attribute.